# Dumb question, alternative approach. Algebraic structure of operators

Tags: abstract-algebra, normed-spaces

The question goes like,

Let $||\cdot||^1,\ ||\cdot||^2$ be norms, show that $\max(||\cdot||^1,\ ||\cdot||^2)$ is a norm.

The elementary proof is very simple. But my funky brain pops a message to me: Can I think of norms as some algebraic structure, ring, group, field, to name a few, like this structure of norm operators, and $\max$ can be viewed as a linear combination of norms ($\max(a, b)=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$). Then we say, alright, linear operation is somehow preserved under some algebraic structure that our norms form, so that the thing we obtain from it must fall inside of this operator family, such that it is still a norm.

Comment: that reads quite a bit like tropical geometry, maybe you want to give a read into that.